# How see maven check style plugin reports in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, intellij-idea

I have maven project with maven-checkstyle-plugin. After maven build I want to see all checkstyle errors (may be in html page). I install Sonar plugin to Idea, but what next? I can not any window or item in menu, I run mvn checkstyle:check and nothing happened in GUI. So is it possible to see all checkstyle errors (not the xml file in target folder) with Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use the Idea checkstyle plugin - http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=1065.

It is unrelated to the maven build, but once installed you can just point it to the same checkstyle config file as in the maven plugin. This way you get checkstyle errors/warnings already when you are coding.

Comment: For large project it is not very convenient to use Idea plugin, just because every developer has it own settings. Maven provides single settings for all team. Also if you use maven you can use this plugin in continue integration tools. It is for projects, but for me it is not "cool" to look at console and fined checkstyle errors (in my company builds are failed if they contain such errors) that's why I need the way to see all error in one "GUI" place.

Comment: But that's what I am saying. You are defining your style in the maven plugin and when using the Checkstyle Idea plugin you use the same style. IMO the Idea plugin gives you all you ask for.

Comment: This plugin allows to use xml configuration to maven-checkstyle-plugin from URL. Nice!